# How to display respective node data after clicking its link on navigation page

Tags: entities

Im new to Drupal. I want to display all the bundles called 'department' in the navigation link and on clicking each navigation link the respective department node will be displayed. Im not being able to display the corresponding nodes. Here's the code:

```
 $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
 $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'escholar')->propertyCondition('type', 'department')->execute();
 $ids = array();
 foreach($result['escholar'] as $r)
 {
   $ids[] = $r->aid;
 }
$artifacts = entity_load('escholar', $ids);
foreach($artifacts as $key => $artifact)
{
    $items['escholar/' . $artifact->aid] = array(
   'title' => $artifact->title,
   'page callback' => 'escholar_page_view',
   'page arguments' => array(1),
   'access arguments' => array('user access')
  );
}

function escholar_page_view($escholar, $view_mode = 'full') {
// Remove previously built content, if exists.
$escholar->content = array();
if ($view_mode == 'teaser') {
  $escholar->content['title'] = array(
  '#markup' => filter_xss($escholar->title),
  '#weight' => -5,
  );
 }
// Build fields content.
field_attach_prepare_view('escholar', array($escholar->aid => $escholar), $view_mode);
entity_prepare_view('escholar', array($escholar->aid => $escholar));
$escholar->content += field_attach_view('escholar', $escholar, $view_mode);
return $escholar->content;
}
```